# How to make a react bootstrap dropdown with panelgroups

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am trying to make a dropdown where each menuitem will have submenuitems
as

```
Drodown(select)
 1. List item(header)
      Litem-1(subheader)
      Litem-2(subheader)
 2. Header-2(header)
       Litem-2-1(subheader)
       Litem-2-2(subheader)
```

I am using react bootstrap dropdown to achieve this 
where each menuitem would have a panelgroup of items as `Litem-1` and `Litem-2`

So When i click on select the dropdown should open up, but when i click on individual headers(which are not expanded by default), should expand and should not close the dropdown and when clicked on subheaders dropdown has to be closed 
I have tried using **open** option of dropdown ,using this i am trying to control the visibility of the dropdown i could achieve the same for headers when i try to do the same i could not achieve because the event is bubbling up till the parent and dropdown remains open , i also tried to use `stopPropagation` but looks like menuitem is not respecting it not sure why it is the case

I tried to solve this as this
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WONMGd
can some one please comment if this approach is right and also why cannot I use `event.stopPropagation` and prevent default here

Thanks

Comment: Just to clarify, you want `submit` and the `v` button to open the list of headers, then you want a click on the headers to show your subheaders which are hidden by default?

Comment: yes exactly that is what i am looking for

Comment: And when you click on a subheader, then it should close?

Comment: yes my idea is ,when you click on the subheader it has to close and what ever the subheader selected/clickedon its name has to appear on the top after closing

Answer (score 1):

To use panels in the way you sort of want them to you have to set the `accordion` prop on your panel to be true.  Check out the code below:

```
<Dropdown.Menu className="Groups" bsRole="menu">
          <MenuItem  onClick={this.menuItemClickedThatShouldntCloseDropdown.bind(this)}>
           <PanelGroup activeKey="1" accordion activeKey={this.state.activeKey}>
             <Panel header="header1" eventKey='1'>
               <span onClick={this.menuItemShouldCloseDropDown.bind(this)}>Content-1</span>
             </Panel>
              <Panel header="header2" eventKey='2'>
                <span onClick={this.menuItemShouldCloseDropDown.bind(this)}>content=2</span>
             </Panel>
            </PanelGroup>
        </MenuItem>
           <MenuItem  onClick={this.menuItemClickedThatShouldntCloseDropdown}>
            hi
        </MenuItem>
      </Dropdown.Menu>

  </Dropdown>
```

and add this to your class definition:

```
  handleSelect(activeKey) {
    this.setState({ activeKey })
  }
```

This seems to solve at least one of your problems.  Id recommend tearing out the other pseudo-state `this._forceOpen` logic to see what you really need.

Comment: I have considered my approach from this ticket of react bootstrap https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/1490

Comment: Cool i mean if it works and its easy then leave it in

Comment: Thanks for all the time that you have put in